# MVC3 ajax form with confirm javascript popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ajax form in a MVC3 project. I want to have a javascript confirm popup on the submit button.
I can make the popup appear a number of ways but I can't get it to block the submit execution if the user selects the cancel button.

What is the best way to do this?

I have tried using the below js...

```
       function showWarning(e) {
           var answer = confirm('message');
           if (answer) {
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
```

but due to the async nature of ajax if doesn't work.

I'm not writing the ajax call myself. I'm using the ajax.begin form helper like so...

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("LinkName", "Account", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divLinkName", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new {  @id="formLinkName" }))
    {
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LinkName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LinkName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LinkName)
                <input type="submit" value="Set my Link Name" class="button radius small" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: show us how you do the ajax call please

Comment: Can you show your HTML

Comment: I have added the html above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (it is in an Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions()) ):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="if (!confirm('Message')) return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

bind a function onSubmit event of form.

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("LinkName", "Account", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divLinkName", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new {  @id="formLinkName",onsubmit="return takeconfirmation()" }))
```

in javascript add takeconfirmation function:

```
function takeconfirmation(){
return confirm('Are you sure');
}
```